# Remove unused resources from Android app on compile time

Tags: java, android, image, resources, proguard

I am currently trying to remove unused graphical resources from an app in compile time. I know Android Studio can help me manually remove unused ones, but I need to be able to remove them in compile time; this way, I can run Proguard to remove unused classes, and then remove any images referenced from those classes.

Right now I can do this, which gets me any unused image shrunk to a 1x1 black dot:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
        }
    }
}
```

I can't have those files there (even shrunk).
Is there a way to make Proguard actually remove those images (instead of shrink them) or rename them?
Maybe I could use some other tool?

edit: just for clarification, I would need the resources rendered "unused" by Proguard to be removed or renamed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProGuard (or the new Jack compiler) only shrink and obfuscate bytecode. The resource shrinking tool subsequently removes or replaces unused resource files.

ProGuard's commercial extension [DexGuard](https://www.guardsquare.com/dexguard) shrinks, optimizes, and obfuscates bytecode, the Android manifest, resources, resource files, asset files, and native libraries. As far as I'm aware, it's the only tool that analyzes and optimizes all contents at the same time. For instance, it indeed removes unused classes and corresponding unused resources and resource files.

[we develop ProGuard and DexGuard at GuardSquare]

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks a lot for your answer. I understand there is no way to make Proguard remove resources, as this task is fulfilled by another tool. I also understand Dexguard would actually remove (not optimize, but remove) all unused images, am I right?

Comment: That's right, DexGuard removes the unused images. The optimizations for instance include inlining resource constants into code and other resources.

Comment: Thanks a lot Eric. You were very helpful

Comment: I'm using DexGuard and it wrongly removes 2 assets in one of my native library. how can I keep them? I just found keep for packages which not working for asset folder :(

Answer (score 0):

To remove unused resources you can use Android Lint tool from ADT 16. It will help you not only to remove unused resources, but also to find potential bugs.

http://tools.android.com/tips/lint

You can also enable proguard in release mode

The ProGuard tool shrinks, optimizes, and obfuscates your code by removing unused code and renaming classes, fields, and methods with semantically obscure names. The result is a smaller sized .apk file that is more difficult to reverse engineer.

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

You can easily search for unused resources from Android Studio. Just press Control + Alt + Shift + i and type "Unused resources" (without quotes). That will execute lint. Super easy way how run lint commands (and other stuff from IDE).

Comment: Hi Shanto, I belive both Lint and the "Remove Unused Resources" tools from Android Studio are the same. As said, I need something to remove those resources automatically on compile-time; manually removing them is not an option, as some resources left unused after applying Proguard should also be removed.
Thanks for the effort, though

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for some utility, you can use https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-unused-resources/

or https://github.com/KeepSafe/android-resource-remover

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Neh, both tools are to be run before compiling, and so wouldn't remove resources which became "unused" after running Proguard, right?